# How to unblock all threads waiting on a semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, deadlock, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am dealing with a standard producer and consumer problem with finite array (or finitely many buffers ). I tried implementing it using semaphores and I have run into a problem. I want the producer to 'produce' only say 50 times. After that I want the producer thread to join the main thread. This part is easy, but what I am unable to do is to join the consumer threads. They are stuck on the semaphore signaling that there is no data. How do I solve this problem?

One possible option is to have a flag variable which becomes True when producer joins main and after that, the main thread would do post(semaphore) as many times as the number of worker threads. The worker threads would check the flag variable every time after waking up and if True, it would exit the function.

I think my method is pretty inefficient because of the many post semaphore calls. It would be great if I can unblock all threads at once!

Edit: I tried implementing whatever I said and it doesn't work due to deadlock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is the "poison pill" method. It assumes that you know how many consumer threads exist. Assuming there are N consumers, then after the producer has done it's thing, it puts N "poison pills" into the queue. A "poison pill" simply is an object/value that is type-compatible with whatever the producer normally produces, but which is distinguishable from a normal object/value.

When a consumer recognizes that it has eaten a poison pill, it dies.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've done producer consumer structures in C++ in FreeRTOS operating system only, so keep that in mind. That has been my only experience so far with multitasking. I would say that I only used one producer in that program and one consumer. And I've done multitasking  in LabView, but this is little bit different from what you might have, I think.

I think that one option could be to have a queue structure, so that the producer enqueues elements into the queue but if it's full of data, then you can hopefully implement it so that you can make some kind of queue policy as follows.

producer can either

1. block itself until space is available in the queue to enqueue,
2. block itself for certain time period, and continue elsewhere if time spent and didnt succeed in enqueuing data
3. immediately go elsewhere

So it looks like you have your enqueuing policy in order...

The queue readers are able to have similar three type of policies at least in FreeRTOS.

In general if you have a binary semaphore, then you have it so that the sender is sending it, and the receiver is waiting on it. It is used for synchronization or signalling.

In my opinion you have chosen the wrong approach with the "many semaphores" (???)
What you need to have is a queue structure where the producer inputs stuff...
Then, the consumers read from the queue whatever they must do...
If the queue is empty then you need a policy on what the queue reader threads should do.
Policy choice is needed also for those queue readers and semaphore readers on what they should do, when the queue is empty, or if they havent gotten the semaphore received. I would not use semaphores for this kind of problem...

I think the boolean variable idea could work, because you are only writing into that variable in the producer thread. Then the other threads should be able to read and poll that boolean variable if the producer is active...

But I think that you should provide more details what you are trying to do, especially with the consumer threads, how many threads of what kind you have, and what language you are programming in etc...

Comment: Did you try the boolean variable technique? I think you would atleast avoid maybe deadlocking? I think your problem sounds like some threads could be waiting for a semaphore that is never given. So that it sounds like each thread should be waiting on its own personal semaphore and the producer should send all the respective semaphores at the same time when it cannot enqueue anymore ???